# What standard should I use for the naming of my MVC controller services?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following:

```
   public class ContentsController : BaseController {
        private IContentService _content;
        private IPageService pageService;
        private IReferenceService _reference;
        private ISequenceService seqService;

        public ContentsController(
            IContentService contentService,
            IPageService pageService,
            IReferenceService referenceService,
            ISequenceService sequenceService) {
            this._content = contentService;
            this.pageService = pageService;
            this._reference = referenceService;
            this.seqService = sequenceService;
        }
```

Note that it's completely mixed up with different naming standards.

Is there anything recommended for the naming of services that are used by my controller?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it matters as long as you are consistent. I personally prefer:  _{servicename}Service format. ex. _referenceService

```
public class ContentsController : BaseController {
        private IContentService _contentService;
        private IPageService _pageService;
        private IReferenceService _referenceService;
        private ISequenceService _seqService;

        public ContentsController(
            IContentService contentService,
            IPageService pageService,
            IReferenceService referenceService,
            ISequenceService sequenceService) {
            this._contentService = contentService;
            this._pageService = pageService;
            this._referenceService = referenceService;
            this._seqService = sequenceService;
        }
```

Comment: yes, I use this same standard for naming.  I would also remove the this. reference as another standard (albiet off topic from OP question)

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, member variables should begin with an underscore and be descriptive

This is fine

```
private IContentService _content;
```

This is better

```
private IContentService _contentService;
```

BTW, using '`this.`' in your constructor is redundant.

Comment: Using underscores is just one naming style and one that is not universally accepted.

Comment: @svick You are correct, edited my answer.  I do like this convention best as it visually differentiates a member variable, and I can have the exact same name for my parameters (without the underscore), making the code very readable.  Again, just MHO.

Comment: @Forty-Two underscores or no underscores, `this.` or none these are a matter of style. One that makes minimal difference. What is more important is that there is a **consistent** style.

Comment: @james yes, huskey's answer above has already pointed that out, but thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use [Microsoft's Guidelines for Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), so you can check your code with tools like FxCop.

Here are guidelines for your case:

- Do not use underscores, hyphens, or any other nonalphanumeric characters (`contentService` instead of `_contentService`)
- Spell out all words used in a field name. Use abbreviations only if developers generally understand them. Do not use uppercase letters for field names (`sequenceService` instead of `_seqService`)
- Do use camel casing in parameter names (you did)